# React Redux anti pattern to calculate and store results in store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, anti-patterns

I have at least two approaches to solve a problem.

1. Repreform calculations inside views on each update (map, filter, find)
2. Keep an "CurrentState" object inside my redux state.

I choose to create a CurrentState object that stores my calculated result (It calculates the results inside the reducer function).

Approach 2 saves processor calculations, but it feels dirty.

*is it considered an antipatern to have a CurrentState object (updated from the reducer) inside the state*?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a hard anti-pattern.

If you are reading this chances are you don't fully understand redux and I would like to recommend

https://github.com/leoasis/redux-immutable-state-invariant

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear from your question - but I assume that you are talking about situation, that you can compute "result" from other data in your store and asking if storing it (redundantly) in store is good pattern.

Well, generally I would not recommend it as keeping redundant data in store can lead to inconsistent data bugs - if you forgot to keep your data in sync (e.g. when you or someone else working on the project would change one data and forget to change the order place).

The standard patter for this is usually to use selectors and memonization (see https://github.com/reactjs/reselect). The idea is to keep only normalized data in your store but to use selectors in your views. Selectors are responsible to "cache" (memonize) extensive computation. Another advantage of selectors is that it provides level of indirection for your application and you can easily evolve your state (as the project grows) without affecting your whole application. On the other hand for small and one time projects selectors can be just "another" boilerplate - but in general I recommend to use them.